# Converting DataView object to bitmap using javascript

Tags: javascript, dataview, arraybuffer, webusb

i am trying to get image from usb biometric fingerprint reader device using `webusb` api. The data returned from device is a `DataView()` (typed array? arraybuffer?). i google it, and can not find a way to convert/extract image from this dataview object. is it black hole for javascript? I would appreciate any ideas.

logged returned data:

```
DataView(512)
    ArrayBuffer(512)
      [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(512) [19, 1, …]
      [[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(256) [275, 310, …]
      [[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(128) [20316435, 22806905, …]
      [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(512) [19, 1, ..]
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is returned as a DataView for convenience, if you need it as an ArrayBuffer just access the `buffer` property. From an ArrayBuffer you can construct another kind of Typed Array or if you want to treat the data as an image turn it into a data URL for use in an  tag.

Comment: i tagged `webusb` for future searches. i tried data URL. i have four nested arrays, they convert only `Uint8Array()`. as promised, thank you :)